# handle "The operation completed successfully" error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, error-handling

I have a vast application running WPF and I occasionally get the

> The operation completed successfully

error randomly, could be a whole host of things.

Is there any way to trap this code and just restart the app.

I'm already using

```
 #region "Error Checking"
    void OnAppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleError("OnAppDomainUnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject.ToString(), e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    }

    void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        if (e.Exception.InnerException != null)
            error = e.Exception.InnerException.Message;

        HandleError("OnDispatcherUnhandledException", e.Exception.Message.ToString(),error);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    #endregion
```

but this does not appear to catch/handle the error

Comment: This occurs when a Windows api call fails and the code has a bug in the error handling logic, a bug that causes the error code to be reset back to 0.  Not uncommon, error handling code rarely gets tested thoroughly.  It is a needle in the hay stack with the info you provided.

Comment: This error-message occurs when the default constructor for SocketException is used, i.e. new SocketException().

Answer (score 0):

When I Google it seems that it has something to do with SplashScreens...

Maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/wpf/thread/0cbd7d9a-2ebd-413d-b14b-9f1815cd62c4) may help you, or [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362735/splashscreen-throws-exception).

Comment: I am running c# and .net 4.0, this appears to have been a problem with 3.5